# How to get the contact form value in lead form dynamics crm 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-online

**1**.I create one new lead.
**2**.I Assign that lead to "Some person".
**3**.then I qualify the lead as a "contact".
**4**.I mapped **lead form "Firstname" to contact form "Firstname"**.It was working Fine.
my question is,
**5**.Again i make a **mapping contact form "Firstname" to lead form "Firstname"**.It was not working.How to Map this field from contact form to lead form?

or I need to get the contact form value in lead form using javascript.Is this Possible?

Comment: Just to clarify the question based on what I'm seeing in some of the answers below, is the primary question about needing to make a change to the Lead FirstName field from a Contact that was converted from that lead (in the case of someone maybe misspelling the name)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V

Once record is deactivated, you can not edit that any more.

In your scenario, normally this is not possible.
For this you need to do custom implementation like PlugIn, Custom WF, SOAP request etc..
You need to first activate  the Lead record again, then you do your work and deactivate it 
again.

By the way, how you are qualifying the Lead record?

Thanks,

Anish.

Answer (score 1):

V,

There is field(LookUp) "Originating LeadId" in the Account,Contact and Opportunity record.

If any Lead is qualified into Account, Contact and Opportunity then this field
"Originating LeadId" gets automatically mapped tho the Leadrecord.
So, this field have the link to that Lead record.
This is handled by CRM itself if you are using CRM Qulaification Process..:)

You can find this field inn the bottom part of the Contact record.
Hope it helps.

Thanks,

Anish

Comment: Please Mark Up the answer so that i can Mark Up others as well..:)

Comment: How to handle "Originating LeadId".I cant find this in contact form.But i dont know wheather i used "CRM Qulaification Process" ,  can u explain me how to perform those things, thanks

Comment: can u expalin more regarding to map those fields.Because am new to crm.

Comment: Hi V.V, have you got in the above of above answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here is "Originating LeadId" in Contact form:

[image: Originating LeadId in Contcat form]

Here Field contains that Lead record which was converted to the Contact.
From this LookUp yoou can all the fields of that Lead record.

Thanks,

Anish.

Comment: thanks for ur answer , but sry to say,  but still i strugle to find the exact solution.If i click the "originating lead" button it will show the lead form.But all the fields are read only because we change the lead into contact.how to do, If first name in contact form is changed to "Hello" , then the related lead form's first name should be changed to "Hello" , how to do this?.